# How merge two dataframes and keep all values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that I need to merge. However I would like to keep all the values in the columns.
Assign column values from `df2.Emotion` to df1 where are similar words. And where these values are not found in `df1`, assign `NaN`.

### Example

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['love', 'smile', 'happy', 'other'],
    'x': [0.113, 0.110, 0.711, 0.211],
    'y': [0.121, 0.131, 0.611, 0.181],
    'z': [0.121, 0.141, 0.511, 0.991]
})

# Assign the Emotion column to the df1 with similar words
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['smile', 'love', 'happy'],
    'emotion': ['friendly', 'joy', 'joy']
})

# Expected output
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': ['love', 'smile', 'happy', 'other'],
    'x': [0.113, 0.110, 0.711, 0.211],
    'y': [0.121, 0.131, 0.611, 0.181],
    'z': [0.121, 0.141, 0.511, 0.991],
    'emotion': ['joy', 'friendly', 'joy', float('NaN')]
})
```

Comment: this is covered in our ubiquitous merging post: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Please make sure to title pandas questions 'Pandas...' not 'Python...' So they get faster more accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use merge with outer.

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```